# How to use `STORAGE_BLOCKED_LOCATIONS` in storage integrations?

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am new to Snowflake and trying to learn how to use the block locations feature of storage integration.

I've successfully created the integration as follows

```
CREATE OR REPLACE STORAGE INTEGRATION aws_integration_2
  TYPE = EXTERNAL_STAGE
  STORAGE_PROVIDER = 'S3'
  ENABLED = TRUE
  STORAGE_AWS_ROLE_ARN = 'some-value'
  STORAGE_ALLOWED_LOCATIONS = ('s3://snowflake-assgnmt/')
  STORAGE_BLOCKED_LOCATIONS = ('s3://snowflake-assgnmt/secretFolder/');
```

However when I create stage as follows

```
CREATE OR REPLACE STAGE external_aws_upload_2
    STORAGE_INTEGRATION = aws_integration_2
   URL = 's3://snowflake-assgnmt/';
```

it gives the error
**Location 's3://snowflake-assgnmt/' is not allowed by integration AWS_INTEGRATION_2. Please use DESC INTEGRATION to check out allowed and blocked locations.**

What is the correct way to restrict access to certain folder in bucket. It's just for learning , I don't have any professional use case.

Note that I have updated the AWS Role details and am able to query the data in stage when I UNSET the STORAGE_BLOCKED_LOCATIONS. I just have the problem while using it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sub-paths included in the `STORAGE_ALLOWED_LOCATIONS` cannot be included in `STORAGE_BLOCKED_LOCATIONS` and this is clearly documented on Snowflake docs:

`STORAGE_ALLOWED_LOCATIONS = ('cloud_specific_url')`

`Explicitly limits external stages that use the integration to reference one or more storage locations (Amazon S3, Google Cloud Storage, or Microsoft Azure). Supports a comma-separated list of URLs for existing buckets and, optionally, paths used to store data files for loading/unloading. Alternatively supports the * wildcard, meaning “allow access to all buckets and/or paths”.`

`Note that if the STORAGE_ALLOWED_LOCATIONS value includes a specific storage location, all subpaths in the same location must be allowed. No subpath can be included in a STORAGE_BLOCKED_LOCATIONS value. For example, if STORAGE_ALLOWED_LOCATIONS includes storage_location/, then STORAGE_BLOCKED_LOCATIONS cannot include storage_location/path1/. Likewise, if STORAGE_ALLOWED_LOCATIONS includes storage_location/path1/, then STORAGE_BLOCKED_LOCATIONS cannot include storage_location/path1/path2/, and so on.`

Reference from [here](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/sql/alter-storage-integration#parameters).

Comment: Ok, I actually read one such wrong command from another snowflake page.